# How can I prevent HTML5 audio or video from playing when removed from the page?

Tags: html, audio, video

Please feel free to suggest a better title for this post, as I wasn't sure how to properly describe the problem in one short question.

I've got a media player page with an HTML5 player and the option for the visitor to choose to play the video or audio for that page.  While one is playing, a button to switch to the other is available.  For example, if the visitor is playing audio, a "Switch to Video" button is available, which essentially removes the current content and replaces it.  This effectively removes the current HTML5 player from the DOM tree as well, of course. In addition to replacing the content, a 'pause' event is triggered on any audio or video element on the page prior to loading the new content.

Unfortunately, if you switch between audio and video quickly enough, you'll end up with multiple items playing simultaneously.

I need to make sure this doesn't happen.

How can I ensure that when I replace the player, the previously loading file does not play?

To see this happening, go to http://www.onlinechurchmediacenter.com/mc/vertigoelectric/5628, choose either audio or video, and once it starts playing keep clicking the "Play Audio" or "Play Video" link which appears below the player.  If you continuously click this quickly enough, you'll begin to notice multiple instances of the audio/video playing over each other.

Comment: Is it possible to trigger a pause event to all playing elements, before starting to play a new one?

Comment: It should be, but I can't get it to work.  I think part of the problem is that the elements technically no longer exist so they can't be targeted by a trigger yet the audio from their files still play.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise not to remove the elements from the DOM.  Just hide them and trigger the pause.  For good measure, trigger another pause before you play the next item.

Comment: I can ask my boss if he wants me to take the extra time to do this, but it would probably take more redesign/coding than it is worth.  One possible workaround I considered is simply disabling or hiding the 'switch' button for a moment when the content loads, thus preventing rapid clicking...  Do you think that could work?

Comment: That can definitely work.  that has actually been done in the past to prevent people from double-submitting forms.

Comment: I'll try it out.  I think the only possible downside is if this problem is related to how long it take the file to load.  For slower systems, if the media takes longer to load than it takes for the button to be enabled, it might still be happen.

Comment: I haven't done any work on this project in a long time so I I'm not sure remember the outcome.  If I recall correctly, however, I believe it may have just ended up being my own browser causing the issue and not the site scripting...  I thought I had returned to post that, so maybe I'm thinking of a different issue.  I wish I could be more helpful.